# Application Insights java agent - log configuration

Tags: java, log4j2, azure-application-insights

I am using `applicationinsights-agent-3.0.0-PREVIEW.7.jar` with `Log4j2` to log into application insights.
When I was using SDK, I could customize `user_id`, `session_id` etc. Is there an option to do the same but with just a java agent? I searched everywhere, but couldn't find any example or documentation about that.

In ideal solution, customization would be possible at runtime.

Comment: "I could customize user_id, session_id etc" - Can you elaborate a bit more please on what customization you were doing?

Comment: @krishg With usage of ApplicationInsights.xml I can add custom TelemetryInitializer which will set user_id and session_id according to defined fields (let's say env variable).

Comment: I suggest you to create an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/issues)